# std::string value or pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm beginning with C++ and have some trouble with understanding how to pass `std::string` as a parameter to functions.

```
void foo(std::string text)
{
    // ...
}

std::string data = "Hello World!";
foo(data);
```

In this case, if I'm not wrong, the **string value** is passed to the function. So whatever I do to the `text` variable in function `foo`, it won't have any effect on the `data` variable.

But how is it possible that to some functions (for examle `std::getline`) I pass a string in the exact same way and they change its value?

```
std::string row;
std::getline(std::cin, row);
// now the value of row is changed
```

Thanks

Comment: This is so fundamental that it will be explained in your C++ book, just keep on reading.

Comment: I wish I'd have one :)

Comment: Then replace "book" with "tutorial" or whatever source you are learning from.

Comment: The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @MartinHeralecký Get one, or follow a tutorial or course, because this isn't a tutorial site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you have a few options:

1. Pass by value. The function prototype is `void foo(std::string text)` and you call it with `foo(data);`. You correctly observe that any modifications made in `foo` to `data` are not reflected in the caller. Conceptually a deep copy is taken (a compiler might optimise out the copy if there are no side effects in doing so; but you'd be wise not to rely on that).
2. Pass by reference. The function prototype is `void foo(std::string& text)` and you call it with `foo(data);`. Any modifications made in `foo` to `data` **are** reflected in the caller.
3. Pass by `const` reference. The function prototype is `void foo(const std::string& text)` and you call it `foo(data);`. This is my favourite: `foo` is not **allowed** to modify `data`: a compile-time error will be issued on such an attempt. Also a deep copy of the string will not be taken.
4. Pass by pointer. The function prototype is `void foo(std::string* text)` and you call it `foo(&data);` `foo` *can* modify the string.
5. Pass by `const` pointer. The function prototype is `void foo(const std::string* text)` and you call it `foo(&data);`. As in (3), `foo` cannot modify the string passed.

Because the *calling* syntax for 1 and 2 are identical, some folk dislike passing something that can be modified by reference since it's not obvious to the caller that the parameters could be changed.

Comment: In cases 3 and 5, the function can in fact modify the string passed, by casting away the const.

Comment: But the behaviour on doing that is undefined if the "original" variable was `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Pass it by reference:

```
void foo(std::string &text)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't the function then be called by `foo(&data)`?

Comment: So I guess I was wrong when I thought that pointers are the same as referneces, wasn't I?

Comment: References aren't pointers. References are name aliases (i.e., another name for the same object).

Comment: No references are not pointers. Chief differences: references cannot be re-bound, a pointer can be `nullptr`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options to pass variables in C++

1) By value

```
void foo(std::string value) { /* ... */ }
// ... call
foo(data);
```

The copy constructor of `std::string` is used to create a local instance in `foo` and modifications stay in the local instance.

2) By reference

```
void foo(std::string &value) { /* ... */ }
// ... call
foo(data);
```

The parameter variable is referenced, so `value` in `foo` is pointing to the same object that you pass to the function. Changes are reflected in your calling code.

3) By const reference

```
void foo(const std::string &value) { /* ... */ }
// ... call
foo(data);
```

As in (2) the parameter object is referenced rather than creating a new instance. However, the contract is not to modify your `value` inside `foo`. This may be cheaper in terms of memory and performance than (1) where the whole string is copied.

4) By pointer

```
void foo(std::string *value) { /* ... */ }
// ... call
foo(&data);
```

You pass the adress of `data` as parameter to `foo`. It is similar to a reference, just relying on pointer logic. In order to access the string in `value`, you have to dereference the pointer as in `(*value)` or `value->some_string_function()`

5) By pointer to constant object

```
void foo(const std::string *value) { /* ... */ }
// ... call
foo(&data);
```

Similar to (4), but the object that the pointer is referencing is constant like in the reference case (3). Note that the pointer itself is not constant, so it is possible to point it to a different object. However, the pointer is local (the object pointed to is not local though), so changing the pointer adress inside `foo` has no effect on the `data` object.

Comment: Seems Bathsheba was a bit faster typing^^

Comment: But you missed out `const` pointer. Will upvote if you include that.

Comment: @Bathsheba See, you where faster typing :P. I'm sure there are even more perverted ways (like a const reference to some custom type with a constructor thats taking in a `std::string`) to pass a variable, but thats a different story

Comment: @Bathsheba Done, I suppose you are happy now? ;)

Answer (score -1):

The second argument is an output argument. `std::getline(std::cin, row)`;

Comment: You will know what this is meaning after your read more c++ fundamental books.